# merge two json object based on key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to merge two json object based on key value using javascript.

I have two different variable g and c.

terms: All values need to merge.

```
var g = [ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 50, name: 'III', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' } ]


 var c = [ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 42, name: 'ZZZ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' } ]
```

I tried the following code: but i merge  what are have same id in 'c' variable. but i need to merge compare 'g' and 'c'.

```
   var arrayList = [];
    for(var i in g) {
        var getid = g[i].id;
        var getname = g[i].name;
        var getgoal = g[i].goal;
        for(var j in c){
            var compareid = c[j].id;
            if(getid == compareid){
                var obj = {};
                obj.id = getid;
                obj.name = getname;
                obj.goal =  'yes';
                obj.circle = 'yes';
                console.log(obj);
                arrayList.push(obj);
            }
         }

    }
    console.log(arrayList);
```

Expected output:

```
[ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes',circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes',circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes',circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', goal: 'yes' ,circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', goal: 'yes' ,circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', goal: 'yes' ,circle: 'yes'},
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', goal: 'yes' ,circle: 'yes'},
    { id: 50, name: 'III', goal: 'yes' ,circle: 'no'},
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', goal: 'yes' ,circle: 'yes'},
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' ,circle: 'yes'} ,
    { id: 42, name: 'ZZZ', goal: 'no' , circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 100, name: 'JJJ',goal: 'no' , circle: 'yes' }]
```

Comment: What is the problem doing this and what is the  question? So far all you've stated is what you want to do ... not what you've done to try to do it

Comment: sorry i forgot to add my code.

Comment: Need to use only javascript not jquery.

Comment: what is your expected `result in this case` `var g = [ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' },....]` `var c = [ { id: 36, name: 'foo', circle: 'yes' },.....]` ??

Comment: what is expected if two objects have same ids but different names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to push `obj` in the first loop in case the id doesn't exist in `c` and to loop through `c` in case one or more id's of that object does not exist in `g`.

```
var g = [
        { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 57, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 4, name: 'DDD', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 39, name: 'EEE', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 37, name: 'FFF', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 59, name: 'GGG', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 50, name: 'III', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 43, name: 'HHH', goal: 'yes' },
        { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' }
    ],
    c = [
        { id: 36, name: 'AAA', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 57, name: 'CCC', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 42, name: 'ZZZ', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 4, name: 'DDD', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 39, name: 'EEE', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 37, name: 'FFF', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 59, name: 'GGG', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 43, name: 'HHH', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' },
        { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' }
    ],
    arrayList = [], obj_c_processed = [];

for (var i in g) {
    var obj = {id: g[i].id, name: g[i].name, goal: g[i].goal};

    for (var j in c) {
        if (g[i].id == c[j].id) {
            obj.circle = c[j].circle;
            obj_c_processed[c[j].id] = true;
        }
    }

    obj.circle = obj.circle || 'no';
    arrayList.push(obj);
}

for (var j in c){
    if (typeof obj_c_processed[c[j].id] == 'undefined') {
        arrayList.push({id: c[j].id, name: c[j].name, goal: 'no', circle: c[j].circle});
    }
}

console.log(arrayList);
```

Comment: The code is working thanks. Its possible to simplify this code ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can assign multiple variables with only one `var` keyword, seperated by a comma. I simplified that, I removed the `get*` variables and I removed the use of `in_obj_c` using the `||` shorthand (in this case: assign "no" to `obj.circle` if it's empty)

Comment: Hi, I need one more help. The same question but i have 3 variable.  (g,c,and u).  g and c are having same values.    var u = [ { 'id': 101, 'name': 'TTT',"other":"yes" }, { 'id': 40, 'name': 'BBB' ,"other":"yes"}, { 'id': 50, 'name': 'III' ,"other":"yes"}, { 'id': 100, 'name': 'JJJ' ,"other":"yes"} ]

Comment: Expected :  [ { 'id': 36, 'name': 'AAA', 'goal': 'yes','circle': 'yes','other':'no' }, { 'id': 40, 'name': 'BBB', 'goal': 'yes','circle': 'yes','other':'yes'"}, { 'id': 57, 'name': 'CCC', 'goal': 'yes','circle': 'yes','other':'no' }, { 'id': 4, 'name': 'DDD', 'goal': 'yes' ,'circle': 'yes','other':'no' }, { 'id': 39, 'name': 'EEE', 'goal': 'yes' ,'circle': 'yes','other':'no' }, { 'id': 37, 'name': 'FFF', 'goal': 'yes' ,'circle': 'yes','other':'no'}, { 'id': 59, 'name': 'GGG', 'goal': 'yes' ,'circle': 'yes','other':'no'}, { 'id': 50, 'name': III, 'goal': 'yes' ,'circle': 'no','other':'yes'},

Comment: { 'id': 43, 'name': 'HHH', 'goal': 'yes' ,'circle': 'yes','other':'no'}, { 'id': 35, 'name': JJJ, 'goal': 'yes' ,'circle': 'yes','other':'no'} , { 'id': 42, 'name': 'ZZZ', 'goal': 'no' , 'circle': 'yes','other':'no'}, { 'id': 100, 'name': JJJ,'goal': 'no' , 'circle': 'yes' ,'other':'yes'}, { 'id': 101, 'name': TTT,'goal': 'no' , 'circle': 'no' ,'other':'yes'}]

Answer (score 4):

Using undescore.js, you can write some function like this:

```js
var a = [ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 50, name: 'III', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' } ];

var b = [ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 42, name: 'ZZZ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' } ];


function merge_object_arrays (arr1, arr2, match) {
  return _.union(
    _.map(arr1, function (obj1) {
      var same = _.find(arr2, function (obj2) {
        return obj1[match] === obj2[match];
      });
      return same ? _.extend(obj1, same) : obj1;
    }),
    _.reject(arr2, function (obj2) {
      return _.find(arr1, function(obj1) {
        return obj2[match] === obj1[match];
      });
    })
  );
}

document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
  merge_object_arrays(a, b, 'id'), null, 2
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<pre>
</pre>
```

Try running it here.

Comment: How would you chance this to make items from arr2 override arr1 on id = id and name !=name

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery. Try this :

```
var g= [ 
    { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 50, name: 'III', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' } ];


 var c= [ 
    { id: 36, name: 'AAA', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 42, name: 'ZZZ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' } ];

var combine_obj={};
$.extend(combine_obj, g, c);
```

OR using simple javascript

```
var combine_obj={};
for(var key in g)  combine_obj[key]=g[key];
for(var key in c)  combine_obj[key]=c[key];
```

Comment: What are `g` and `c`?

Comment: The objects in their example

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this,

```
var g = [ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 50, name: 'III', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', goal: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', goal: 'yes' } ]


 var c = [ { id: 36, name: 'AAA', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 40, name: 'BBB', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 57, name: 'CCC', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 42, name: 'ZZZ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DDD', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 39, name: 'EEE', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 37, name: 'FFF', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 59, name: 'GGG', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 43, name: 'HHH', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 35, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' },
    { id: 100, name: 'JJJ', circle: 'yes' } ]

for (i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {        //Loop trough first array
    var curID = g[i].id;                //Get ID of current object
    var exists = false;                 
    for (j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {    //Loop trough second array
        exixts = false;
        if (curID == c[j].id){          //If id from array1 exists in array2
            exixts = true;
            tempObj = c[j];             //Get id,object from array 2
            break;
        }
    }
    if(exixts) {
        g[i]["circle"] = tempObj.circle;//If exists add circle from array2 to the record in array1
    }else{
        g[i]["circle"] = "no";          //If it doesn't add circle with value "no"
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {        //Loop trough array 2
    var curObj = c[i];
    var ex = true;
    g.forEach(function(row) {           //Loop to check if id form array2 exists in array1
        if (curObj.id == row.id){
            ex = false;
        }
    });
    if(ex){                             //If it doesn't exist add goal to object with value "no" and push it into array1
        curObj["goal"] = "no";
        g.push(curObj);
    }
}

console.debug(g);
```

I've added some comments to explain what is going on in the code.

Psuedo code,

```
//Loop trough g
//get id from g[i] and check if it exists in c
//if so
    //add circle from a2 to a1[i]
    //Add value of circle from c onto g[i]["circle"]
//otherwise
    //Add value of "no" onto g[i]["circle"]

//Loop trough c
    //If id isn't in g, add row with value c[i]["goal"] = "no" to g
```