# join two json files based on common key with jq utility or alternative way from command line

Tags: json, inner-join, jq

I have 2 json files with common key and I need to JOIN them with ***jq*** utility or alternative way from command line As follows:

(for example: jq -join -key "id" jsonFile1 jsonFile2)

jsonFile1:

```
{"id":"10","data":"abc"}
{"id":"20","data":"xyz"}
{"id":"30","data":"qwe"}
{"id":"40","data":"wsx"}
{"id":"50","data":"zxc"}
```

jsonFile2:

```
{"id":"60","content":"ert"}
{"id":"40","content":"tgb"}
{"id":"10","content":"yui"}
{"id":"30","content":"ujm"}
{"id":"70","content":"rfv"}
```

output:

```
{"id":"10","data":"abc","content":"yui"}
{"id":"30","data":"qwe","content":"ujm"}
{"id":"40","data":"wsx","content":"tgb"}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093561/merge-two-json-object-based-on-key-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

This response illustrates an efficient approach using jq.

In the example, the value of .id in each object is a string
and therefore in the first part of this response, it is assumed that the key is always string-valued (in the P.S., this assumption is relaxed).

It is also assumed that the "rows" can be combined without regard to conflicting values.  (We use jq's `+` to combine objects.)

```
# hashJoin(a1; a2; field) expects a1 and a2 to be arrays of JSON objects
# and that for each of the objects, the field value is a string.
# A relational join is performed on "field".

def hashJoin(a1; a2; field):
  # hash phase:
  (reduce a1[] as $o ({};  . + { ($o | field): $o } )) as $h1
  | (reduce a2[] as $o ({};  . + { ($o | field): $o } )) as $h2
  # join phase:
  | reduce ($h1|keys[]) as $key
      ([]; if $h2|has($key) then . + [ $h1[$key] + $h2[$key] ] else . end) ;

hashJoin( $file1; $file2; .id)[]
```

Invocation:

```
$ jq -nc --slurpfile file1 file1.json --slurpfile file2 file2.json -f join.jq
```

Output:

```
{"id":"10","data":"abc","content":"yui"}  
{"id":"30","data":"qwe","content":"ujm"}
{"id":"40","data":"wsx","content":"tgb"}
```

P.S. Here is a still more efficient implementation of `hashJoin/3`, which relaxes all assumptions about the specified "key" except that it specify a valid key. Composite keys can be specified as arrays.

```
def hashJoin(a1; a2; key):
  def akey: key | if type == "string" then . else tojson end;
  def wrap: { (akey) : . } ;
  # hash phase:
  (reduce a1[] as $o ({};  . + ($o | wrap ))) as $h1
  | (reduce a2[] as $o 
      ( {};
        ($o|akey) as $v
        | if $h1[$v] then . + { ($v): $o } else . end )) as $h2
  # join phase:
  | reduce ($h2|keys[]) as $key
      ([];  . + [ $h1[$key] + $h2[$key] ] ) ;
```

Comment: In case this was not obvious to anyone, you should save the hashJoin script as join.jq (-f means read filter from file). If you have the same field in both files, you will also lose one of them.

Comment: Is there a non-efficient but more succinct solution available?

Answer (score 0):

@user239558 asked:

> Is there a ... more succinct solution available?

The following solution is both efficient and more succinct:

```
jq --slurpfile file2 file2.json '
  INDEX($file2[]; .id) as $dict
  | $dict[.id] as $x
  | if $x then . + $x else empty end
'  file1.json
```