# JQ Join JSON files by key

Tags: json, file, join, key, jq

Looks like [it's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830426/join-two-json-files-based-on-common-key-with-jq-utility-or-alternative-way-from) not actual for jq 1.4, could you provide any other ways to join JSON files by key?
e.g

```
{
    "key": "874102296-1",
    "que_lat": "40"
}
{
  "key": "874102296-2",
  "que_lat": "406790"
}
```

and

```
{
  "key": "874102296-1",
  "in_time": "1530874104733",
  "latency": "12864258288242"
}
{
  "key": "874102296-2",
  "in_time": "1530874104746"
}
```

As a result, i'd like to have something like this:

```
{
  "key": "874102296-1",
  "in_time": "1530874104733",
  "full_latency": "12864258288242",
  "que_lat": "40"
}
{
  "key": "874102296-2",
  "in_time": "1530874104746",
  "que_lat": "406790"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can easily be solved using the def of hashJoin given in the SO page that you cite.

### Solution using jq 1.5 or higher

If you have jq 1.5 or higher, you could use this invocation:

```
jq -n --slurpfile f1 file1.json --slurpfile f2 file2.json -f join.jq
```

where join.jq contains the second def of hashJoin, together with:

```
hashJoin($f1; $f2; .key)[]
```

### Solution using jq 1.4

If you have jq 1.4, the trickiness is to read each of the two files separately as an array. Here's one approach that assumes bash:

```
jq -n --argfile f1 <(jq -s . file1.json) --argfile f2 <(jq -s . file2.json) -f join.jq
```

where join.jq is as above.

If you cannot use bash, then it might be simplest to create temporary files.