# Merge 2 arrays of objects based on different key but same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-merge

I have referred questions listed below, but got not related answer.

1. [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)
2. [merge two json object based on key value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093561/merge-two-json-object-based-on-key-value-in-javascript)
3. [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

I have 2 arrays of objects,

OBJ1 -

```
[
    {
        "ID": 58895,
        "step": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"
    },
    {
        "ID": 58896,
        "step": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"
    }
]
```

OBJ2 -

```
[
    {
        "type": "verification_step",
        "value": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"
    },
    {
        "type": "verification_step",
        "value": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"
    }
]
```

I want to have the output which contains the both values in the single object based on the value of the string i.e.

```
[
    {
        "ID": 58896,
        "type": "verification_step",
        "step": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"
    },
    {
        "ID": 58895,
        "type": "verification_step",
        "step": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"
    }
]
```

Please suggest me the way out. (ES6 solution - much appreciated)

**Edit**

The 3rd reference which have assiged as duplicate is not the scenario. The key should remain "step" and the data should be merged.

Comment: are the step and value in obj1 and obj2 are equal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: OBJ1.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  type: OBJ2.find(item2 => item2.value === item.step).type,
}))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` after combining both the arrays.

```js
const arr1 = [ { "ID": 58895, "step": "Outage Agreed w/ Business" }, { "ID": 58896, "step": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant" } ] 

const arr2 = [ { "type": "verification_step", "value": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant" }, { "type": "verification_step", "value": "Outage Agreed w/ Business" } ]

const res = [...arr1,...arr2.map(({value,...rest}) => ({step:value,...rest}))].reduce((ac,a) => {
  let k = a.step;
  ac[k] = {...ac[k],...a} || a;
  return ac;
},{})
console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: Is that possible that the key remain to be "step" instead of "value"?

Comment: @KeyurK Please add the expected ouput.

Comment: Edited the expected output

Comment: This is not I wanted Maheer. I want to compare the string and then merge the data. I have not only ID to be merged.

Comment: @KeyurK I know that. It will work for more properties. My gives the correct output i guess that you have posted. Can you please tell where it fails?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do this as a one liner, but for readability and efficiency it might be nicer to make a lookup object based on the value you want from one of the arrays and then `map` the other other array using the lookup to join the other value you want. Something like:

```js
let arr1 = [{"ID": 58895,"step": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"},{"ID": 58896,"step": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"}]
let arr2 = [{"type": "verification_step","value": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"},{"type": "verification_step","value": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"}]

// lookup based on value
let lookup = arr2.reduce((m, {type, value}) => m.set(value, {type}), new Map)

// merge each item based on lookup
let result = arr1.map(item =>  Object.assign({}, item, lookup.get(item.step)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/key-by/):

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const arr1 = [
    {
        "ID": 58895,
        "step": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"
    },
    {
        "ID": 58896,
        "step": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"
    }
]

const arr2 = [
    {
        "type": "verification_step",
        "value": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"
    },
    {
        "type": "verification_step",
        "value": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"
    }
]
const res =  _(arr1)
    .keyBy('step')
    .merge((_.keyBy(arr2, 'value')))
    .values()
    .map((value) => {
      const { ID, type, step } = value
      return {
         ID, 
         type, 
         step
      }
    })
    .value()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need ES6, you can just use the map operator and concatenate the missing value to just on object.
like this

```
let obj=[
    {
        "type": "verification_step",
        "value": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"
    },
    {
        "type": "verification_step",
        "value": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"
    }
]

const obj1=[
    {
        "ID": 58895,
        "step": "Outage Agreed w/ Business"
    },
    {
        "ID": 58896,
        "step": "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant"
    }
]


obj.map((ob)=>{
    const found=obj1.find((e)=>{
        return e.step===ob.value;
    });
    if(found){
        ob.ID=found.ID
    }
});
```

There might be a typo, i just typed it but you get the idea.
You need to do necessary check to avoid undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you can just write 
Here's the link for testing [online es6 compiler](https://repl.it/repls/WellmadeMiserableFont)

```
let arr = [];
 obj1.map((val, index) => {
  if(obj2[index]) {
   arr.push({ id: val.ID, type: obj2[index].type, value: obj2[index].value })
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Map` for `ID` and get this value for mapping new objects.

```js
var array1 = [{ ID: 58895, step: "Outage Agreed w/ Business" }, { ID: 58896, step: "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant" }],
    array2 = [{ type: "verification_step", value: "GMLC/E911/CMAS Significant" }, { type: "verification_step", value: "Outage Agreed w/ Business" }],
    map = new Map(array1.map(({ ID, step }) => [step, ID])),
    result = array2.map(({ type, value: step }) => ({ ID: map.get(step), type, step }));

console.log(result);
```