# How to do a join from 2 JSON by a common ID field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two JSON files: JSON A has some company properties and the company_id, while JSON B has company names and company ids.

JSON A example:

```
[
  {
    "order_name": "Foo",
    "company_id": "112233"
  },
  {
    "order_name": "Bar",
    "company_id": "123456"
  }
]
```

JSONB example:

```
[
  {
     "company_id":"112233",
     "name":"ACME company",
  },
  {
     "company_id":"123456",
     "name":"John Doe Inc.",
  }
]
```

Which is the most efficient way to do a join by the `company_id` values? I would like to have the JSON C (merged result) with the company names correctly added, like this:

```
[
  {
    "order_name": "Foo",
    "company_id": "123456",
    "company_name": "John Doe Inc."
  },
  {
    "order_name": "Bar",
    "company_id": "112233",
    "company_name": "ACME company"
  }
]
```

Is looping and filter for each the only solution? Is there a more efficient way to do this from a performance point of view?

More info:

- JSON is not sorted by company_id.
- Array A could have more than one object with the same `company_id`
- I'm using Javascript (in a Vue.js app), I don't need to support old browsers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093561/merge-two-json-object-based-on-key-value-in-javascript

Comment: _"Which is the most efficient way..."_ - Asks for an (most likely) opinion-based answer. And what defines "efficiency" in the first place?

Comment: @Andreas aren't this JSON objects? For efficiency I mean from a performance point of view, I've added it on the question, thanks.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson This solutions should work, but is there a better way (lesser code, better performance) to do this nowadays, like using "filter" or "map"?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common modern JavaScript, you can do this as you mentioned with higher-order functions like `map`, `filter`, and so on:

```js
const arrayA = [
  {
    "order_name": "Foo",
    "company_id": "112233"
  },
  {
    "order_name": "Bar",
    "company_id": "123456"
  }
]

const arrayB = [
  {
     "company_id":"112233",
     "name":"ACME company",
  },
  {
     "company_id":"123456",
     "name":"John Doe Inc.",
  }
]

const mergeAB = arrayA.map( companyA => {
    const matched = arrayB.find(companyB => companyB.company_id === companyA.company_id)
    if(matched) {
      return {...companyA, ...matched}
    } else {
      // return companyA element or customize it with your case
    }
  }
)

console.log(mergeAB)
```

**Note 1**: `Array.find()` method complexity is **O(n)** and `Array.map()` method complexity is **O(n)**

**Note 2:** efficiency is an important thing but not in all situations. sometimes you need to do these types of iteration one time or for a small array size, so no need to worry about the performance.

**Note 3:** you could compare the answer and find out your best solution since we don't know about your whole code and application.

Comment: Tip: if you leave the else empty as this example, you can have "undefined" values. I suggest to return {...companyA} to have a complete array.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, as you can see I recommend returning compnayA in else block.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will work for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {
    "order_name": "Foo",
    "company_id": "112233"
  },
  {
    "order_name": "Bar",
    "company_id": "123456"
  }
];

const arrayTwo = [
  {
     "company_id":"112233",
     "name":"ACME company",
  },
  {
     "company_id":"123456",
     "name":"John Doe Inc.",
  }
];

const [source, target] = arrayOne.length > arrayTwo.length
  ? [arrayOne, arrayTwo]
  : [arrayTwo, arrayOne];
  
const merged = source.map(object =>
{
    // Assuming that in the 2nd array, the match is only found 1 time and it EXISTS.
    
    const matched = target.find(element => element.company_id === object.company_id);
    
    // Merge both objects together
    
    return {
         ...object,
         ...matched
    };
});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: your code implementation is correct at all but needs more attention, the "matched" object could be "undefined". spread an undefined object will cause an exception.

Comment: If you check the comment, I specifically wrote that "Assuming that the object exists" and your solution is EXACTLY like mine.

Answer (score 1):

By having JSONs:

```
const jsonA = [
    {
      "order_name": "Foo",
      "company_id": "112233"
    },
    {
      "order_name": "Bar",
      "company_id": "123456"
    }
];

const jsonB = [
    {
       "company_id":"112233",
       "name":"ACME company",
    },
    {
       "company_id":"123456",
       "name":"John Doe Inc.",
    }
];
```

you can merge maps into 3rd map with something like this:

```
const transform = (data, current={}) => 
    data.reduce((prev, company) => {
        if(!prev[company['company_id']]) prev[company['company_id']] = {};
        prev[company['company_id']] = {...prev[company['company_id']], ...company}
        return prev;
    }, current);

let jsonMap = transform(jsonA, {});
jsonMap = transform(jsonB, jsonMap);

let jsonC = Object.keys(jsonMap).map(companyId => jsonMap[companyId] );
console.log(jsonC);
```